# Can someone help me debug this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text t1 SET value = (SELECT value FROM
 (SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_text t2 WHERE t2.value_id =
 (t1.value_id+2)) AS t3)
```

This is what PhpMyAdmin tells me when I try to run this query:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 't1.value_id' in 'where clause'
```

Here's what my structure looks like:

[image: Structure example]

I want to bring `value` column lines 2 rows up each, leaving the last two lines empty, fixing the import mistake caused by placing two additional lines to the top of the column.

Comment: Instead of nesting sub-selects like this, consider a self-join. I'm dusting off sqlfiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text t1 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text t2
ON t2.value_id = t1.value_id+2
SET t1.value = t2.value
```

**Update 1** @mabi if you are talking about OP *#1054 - Unknown column 't1.value_id' in 'where clause'*.

This error is about the rule - you can't call parent table inside subquery. It is about namespacing inside the query. So if you do

```
select * 
from a 
join (
  select *
  from b
) as b1
```

you can't use `a` when `(select from b)` and by the way you can't access `b` on the `a` level you can only use `b1`.

Comment: Seconds before me hitting the post button ;-) Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b343f/1
Now, if you can also add why `t1` isn't resolved as an alias that would make it complete.